# Getting all routes from current module - Angular 2

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing

Hi m using lazy loading in my sample.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: 'comp1', loadChildren: 'app/components/comp1/comp1.module#comp1Module' },
   { path: 'comp2', loadChildren: 'app/components/comp2/comp2.module#comp2Module' },
. . .

]
```

comp1Module having below sub routes Routes

```
export const comp1Routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'comp1/default', component: DefaultComponent },
 ];
```

While routing i need to get all routed from the module.

For ex: I want get all routes from the module **comp1**

Comment: Well depending on where you "need" it `router.config` should give you the `Routes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the router.config by injecting Router and pull the config.

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  console.log(this.router.config);
}
```

Comment: But `this.router.config` gives you all routes from the `app.routing` and not the routes of current lazy loaded module. Tested on `angular@5.0.1` with 2-level lazy modules.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

Define your lazy-loaded module routes as children of a root component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LazyLoadedRootComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
            { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyLoadedRootComponent, Child1Component, Child2Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class LazyLoadedModule { }
```

Then from your root module component you can get its children routes like that:

```
export class LazyLoadedRootComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.route.routeConfig.children);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your app-routing.module.ts looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'first-module',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/first-module/first.module').then(m => m.FirstModule)
},
{
    path: 'second-module',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/second-module/second.module').then(m => m.SecondModule)
},
```

And your first-routing.module.ts looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'first-page',
    component: FirstPageComponent,
    data: {
        someData: 'abc'
    }
},
{
    path: 'second-page',
    component: SecondPageComponent,
    data: {
        extendedData: 'XYZ'
    }
},
```

You get the routes and config to specific module-routes like this.
Without that any-cast, you will get error "Property '_loadedRoutes' does not exist on type 'Route'."

```
private getModuleRoutes(): Route[] {
    return (this.router.config.find(routeConfig=>
        routeConfig.path === 'first-module'
    ) as any)._loadedRoutes;
}
```